# Angular 2 Observable.forkJoin results

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have following code in my component:

```
public user: User;
public roles: Role[];
public organizations: Organization[];

public ngOnInit() {
  this.user$ = this.userService.getUser(1).share();
  this.roles$ = this.roleService.getRoles().share();
  this.organizations$ = this.organizationService.getOrganizations().share();

  Observable.forkJoin([this.user$, this.roles$, this.organizations$]).subscribe(data => {      
    this.user = data[0];
    this.roles = data[1];
    this.organizations = data[2];
  });
}
```

This should work I think but I am getting error in IDEA and it wont even compile, I am stuck on this for some time now, can anyone help?

[image]

Service methods looks like this:

```
public getRoles(): Observable<Role[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.API_URL).map(res => res.json());
 }
```

Comment: can you share the getRoles from service

Comment: I added one service method to the code

Comment: I've got an impression that your compiler chooses a wrong observable creation method overload and defines the `forkJoin` return value type by the type of the first observable. Could you try to pass observables as a plain arguments, without wrapping them into an array, like this: `forkJoin(this.user$, this.roles$, this.organizations$)`? Let's see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Omg that worked :-D Thank you!!

Comment: Glad that I could help : )

Comment: I read somewhere that it should be an array... never thought about trying it without it. You saved my day thanks again.